# Effective way to parse xml to JSON format to get the data dynamically

Tags: python, json, xml, xml-parsing

Trying to parse XML and to store it in json format. I want to do dynamically,so that for different api keys it will also work. How to change this to dynamically to retrieve data from XML and pass it in JSON format? I need details inside **PNRAmount** in xml file.

Code:
`

```
pnr = myroot.xpath("/Envelope/Body/q:SellResponse/r:BookingUpdateResponseData/r:Success/r:PNRAmount",namespaces=namespace)

balanceDue = pnr[0][0].text.strip()
AuthorizedBalanceDue = pnr[0][1].text.strip()
SegmentCount = pnr[0][2].text.strip()
PassiveSegmentCount = pnr[0][3].text.strip()
TotalCost = pnr[0][4].text.strip()
PointsBalanceDue = pnr[0][5].text.strip()
TotalPointCost = pnr[0][6].text.strip()
AlternateCurrencyBalanceDue = pnr[0][7].text.strip()


# for pnrDetails in pnr:
PNR = {
        "BalanceDue" : balanceDue,
        "AuthorizedBalanceDue" : AuthorizedBalanceDue,
        "SegmentCount": SegmentCount,
        "PassiveSegmentCount":PassiveSegmentCount,
        "TotalCost":TotalCost,
        "PointsBalanceDue": PointsBalanceDue,
        "TotalPointCost":TotalPointCost,
        "AlternateCurrencyBalanceDue":AlternateCurrencyBalanceDue

    }

print(PNR)
```

XML Code:
`

```
<Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <SellResponse xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/BookingService">
            <BookingUpdateResponseData xmlns="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Booking" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Success>
                    <RecordLocator />
                    <PNRAmount type = "true">
                        <BalanceDue>
                            4880.00000
                        </BalanceDue>
                        <AuthorizedBalanceDue>
                            4880.00000
                        </AuthorizedBalanceDue>
                        <SegmentCount>
                            1
                        </SegmentCount>
                        <PassiveSegmentCount>
                            0
                        </PassiveSegmentCount>
                        <TotalCost>
                            4880.00000
                        </TotalCost>
                        <PointsBalanceDue>
                            0
                        </PointsBalanceDue>
                        <TotalPointCost>
                            0
                        </TotalPointCost>
                        <AlternateCurrencyBalanceDue>
                            0
                        </AlternateCurrencyBalanceDue>
                    </PNRAmount>
                </Success>
                <Warning i:nil="true" />
                <Error i:nil="true" />
                <OtherServiceInformations i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Common" />
            </BookingUpdateResponseData>
        </SellResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I've tried the static way, writing path for each tag and getting the value by .text method. I want to get the data dynamic way such that if key is different it will work.

Trying to do something like this

```
 vehicle_response = detail_root.xpath('/x:Envelope/x:Body/y:VehicleLocationDetailRsp',
                                         namespaces=optionstravel_vehicle_ns())[0]

counter_location = vehicle_response.xpath('y:LocationInfo',
                                              namespaces=optionstravel_vehicle_ns())[0].get('CounterLocation')
```

Then passing **counter_location** as value in json.

Comment: Did you try something like that? 
 https://linuxhint.com/python_xml_to_dictionary/

Comment: I want to know the method

Comment: The article axplains the process in detail. In generat the xmltodict.parse() method creates a nested OrderedDict out of your XLM - so will have your data ready somewhere in there. I am not sure if I follow your requirements though.

Comment: This method (XMLtoDict) takes to much time. I need more efficient one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SAX interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.handler.html) which is built-in in Python. SAX offers sort of event-based XML parsing mechanism. It is rather helpful in your case since you want to parse only particular section of XML document. One has to implement a custom ContentHandler class to succeed.

Based on that [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-xml-parser/#xmlsax-the-sax-interface-for-python), below is a handler class and respective code to parse your XML file into JSON file:

```
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
from xml.sax import parse
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

class MyXmlPayloadHandler(ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self, section = ""):
        super().__init__()
        self.desired_section_name = section  # target section of XML doc
        self.desired_section_ongoing = False
        self.current_element = ""  # currently ongoing key/property/element name
        self.output_dict = OrderedDict() # the actual dictionary which will be subjected to jsonification

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        """ Called by the parser when new XML element begins """
        if self.desired_section_ongoing:
            self.current_element = name
            self.output_dict[name] = ""
        if self.desired_section_name in name:
            self.desired_section_ongoing = True

    def endElement(self, name):
        """ Called by the parser when XML element ends """
        # todo: you might want to implement conversion to int here,
        # i.e. at the end of each element
        if self.desired_section_ongoing:
            if self.desired_section_name in name:
                self.desired_section_ongoing = False

    def characters(self, content):
        """ Called by the parser to add characters to the element's value """
        if content.strip() != "":
            if self.desired_section_ongoing:
                # add the characters to the current element value
                self.output_dict[self.current_element] += content

# do the job
handler = MyXmlPayloadHandler(section = "PNRAmount")
parse(r"examples\sample.xml", handler)

# dumping the dict into json file
with open("datadict.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(handler.output_dict, f, indent=4)
```

Resulting `datadict.json` file:

```
{
    "BalanceDue": "4880.00000",
    "AuthorizedBalanceDue": "4880.00000",
    "SegmentCount": "1",
    "PassiveSegmentCount": "0",
    "TotalCost": "4880.00000",
    "PointsBalanceDue": "0",
    "TotalPointCost": "0",
    "AlternateCurrencyBalanceDue": "0"
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to do another way around.

Comment: @mzjn thanks, I elaborated on my answer a bit...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pandas** `read_xml()` for parsing the XML and write it to `to_json()`, [Source](https://datatofish.com/export-pandas-dataframe-json/):

```
import pandas as pd

xml = 'Gorantula.xml'
namespaces={"xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
            "xmlns": "http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Booking",
            "xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}

df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath="//xmlns:PNRAmount", namespaces=namespaces)
df1 = df.T

df1.to_json(r'Gorantula.json')
print(df1)
```

Output this file:

```
{"0":{"type":true,
    "BalanceDue":4880.0,
    "AuthorizedBalanceDue":4880.0,
    "SegmentCount":1,
    "PassiveSegmentCount":0,
    "TotalCost":4880.0,
    "PointsBalanceDue":0,
    "TotalPointCost":0,
    "AlternateCurrencyBalanceDue":0}}
```